# Horizontal recyclerview into vertical recyclerview at specific position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to insert/show horizontal recyclerview into specific position (at this example position:1)

Vertical recyclerview - displays TextView + shape (rectange)
Horizontal recyclerview - displays ImageViews (next to each other)

**.XML's**

horizontal_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:padding="0dp"/>
```

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.mkalejs.training.MainActivity">
```

vertical_layout.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/vertical_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:padding="0dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

vertical_layout_item.xml

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lbl_url_text"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Name" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/rectangle"
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle" />
```

horizontal_layout_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
android:visibility="visible"
android:weightSum="1">


<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/img_horizontal_slider"
    android:layout_width="33dp"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:visibility="visible" />


 </LinearLayout>
```

There might be a small misunderstanding in recyclerview concept. I'm not sure where I can call `horizontal_recyclerview"` to not return it as a null (as I am now) and populate it with data. Is the XML structure wrong? Feel free to update code parts.

---

**THIS SHOULD BE OKAY**

MainActivity.class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.vertical_layout);

        ArrayList<PictureData> bundleOfData =  prepareData();

        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.vertical_recyclerview);
        VerticalAdapter adapter = new VerticalAdapter(bundleOfData, this);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
        //rv.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }
```

VerticalAdapter.class

```
public class VerticalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<PictureData> pictures;
    Context context;

    public VerticalAdapter(ArrayList<PictureData> pictures, Context context) 
    {
        this.pictures = pictures;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView;
        switch (viewType) {
            case 1:
                itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.horizontal_layout_item, parent, false);
                return new HorizontalViewHolder(itemView);
            default:
                itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.vertical_layout_item, parent, false);
                return new VerticalViewHolder(itemView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()){
            case 1:
                HorizontalViewHolder hVh = (HorizontalViewHolder) holder;
                HorizontalAdapter horizontal_adapter = new HorizontalAdapter(pictures, context);
                hVh.horizontal_rec.setAdapter(horizontal_adapter);
                break;
            default:
                VerticalViewHolder vVh = (VerticalViewHolder) holder;
                vVh.textView.setText(pictures.get(position).getPictureUrl());
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {return pictures.size();}

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(position == 1){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

HorizontalViewHolder.class

**I GET A ERROR HERE. OBVIOUSLY, I DON'T HAVE `(img_horizontal_slider)` IN HORIZONTAL_LAYOUT, but putting ImageView + RecyclerView in one layout file and call here would feel wrong (?)**

```
public class HorizontalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public ImageView imagePositionInLayout;
    public RecyclerView horizontal_rec;

    public HorizontalViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(itemView.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        horizontal_rec = itemView.findViewById(R.id.vertical_recyclerview);
        imagePositionInLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_horizontal_slider);
        horizontal_rec.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }

    public ImageView getView() {
        return imagePositionInLayout;
    }
}
```

HorizontalAdapter.class

```
ublic class HorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<PictureData> pictures;
    Context context;

    public HorizontalAdapter(ArrayList<PictureData> pictures, Context context) {
        this.pictures = pictures;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public HorizontalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.horizontal_layout_item, parent, false);
        return new HorizontalViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HorizontalViewHolder holder, int position) 
    {
        Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context);
        Picasso picasso = builder.build();
        picasso
                .load("http://nuclearpixel.com/content/icons/2010-02-09_stellar_icons_from_space_from_2005/earth_128.png")
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .into(holder.imagePositionInLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return pictures.size();
    }


}
```

I'm new to Android so I hope people will give some good explanation on what is wrong and how to fix it. Every suggestion will be gladly accepted. I will highly appreciate if someone will actually look into this and explain, because I feel pretty lost right now.

Comment: I understood the part I got lost - onCreateView method returns specific view which needs to have some type of layout.
Ex.
hor_layout - holds only RecycleView.
hor_layout_item - holds only ImageView.

As I understood, I can only pass one layout to ViewHolder, so, for instance, if I pass hor_layout, I'll have access to RV, but not for ImageView. Obviously, there could be solution to put both elements in one layout, but that would make unneeded space (RV under ImageView) and probably there's other easier solution. Any ideas? Thanks.